# Help with the limiting behavior of a stochastic process

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes

I'm doing a problem set in a college algebra text, at the end of a chapter on matrix arithmetic. There's a problem where, given matrices
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
0.90 & 0.20\\
0.10 & 0.80
\end{bmatrix}, X=\begin{bmatrix}
150\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
we compute $Q^nX$ for various values of $n$ to see where it's headed as $n$ increases, and we're asked to show that $Q^nX\to \begin{bmatrix}100\\50\end{bmatrix}$ as $n\to \infty$. I'm not sure how to prove such a thing, beyond observing that it appears to be headed that way. I suspect we're not meant to prove it rigorously, given the level of the book, but maybe I'm wrong about that. If we are meant to prove it, I have no idea how to go about doing so.

It then asks us to show that $Q^n\to\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{3} &\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Does it sound like I should just "show" and not "prove"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if they want you to prove it, but if so here's how:

If you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors, you can diagonalize the matrix $Q$ 
and come up with an explicit formula for the powers of $Q$. As a sanity check, note that for $n=0$ this gives the right answer, i.e., the identity matrix.

$$Q^n=\pmatrix{\frac{2}{3} &\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}}
+\left({7\over 10}\right)^n\pmatrix{\frac{1}{3} &\frac{-2}{3}\\\frac{-1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}}.$$

Now let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: This looks like it's beyond the scope of the book, but I appreciate the help! I guess we're just supposed to observe the behavior so we'll be familiar with it when we have the necessary tools (like those you've presented) for more rigorous analysis.

Comment: @ivan Since you tagged the question *stochastic processes* I should mention that the result also follows from Markov chain theory. But the proof is not any easier than the linear algebra proof that I give above.

Comment: Good to know. I'm slogging through this algebra text for review, and looking forward to getting to the more advanced stuff :)